# Launch Gnome-Terminal and bring to front

Tags: linux, gnome-terminal

Our Java-based application has a command to open the gnome-terminal in a certain directory. It invokes following command

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --working-directory <dir>
```

The terminal window opens (verified on stock Ubuntu 16.04), but unfortunately only in the background. How to launch it (without the need to install any additional software, because it should work on any user machine) so it will occur as active window?